# Separate each piece of data

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

If I'm retrieving more than 1 piece of data from mySql, how can I separate it in my js file. So I can use each piece of data in specific locations?

```
var hr = new XMLHttpRequest();
var pUrl = "../thephp.php";
hr.open("GET", pUrl, true);
hr.setRequestHeader("Contenet-type", "application/x-www-form-unlencoded");

hr.onreadystatechange = function(){
    if(hr.readyState == 4 && hr.status ==200){
        var return_data = hr.responseText;
    }
}
//ASSUMING 'logo1.jpg'  and  'Group Melago' are been sent via the php. how can I define them individually
var image = { 
    'back': { 'url':'img/logo1.jpg', 'img':null },
};
    var group ='Group Melago';
```

php

```
$query = $db->prepare('SELECT logoImage, groupName FROM sports WHERE eligible = ? ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 1');
$array = array('N');
$query->execute($array);
$result = $query->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
var_dump($result);
```

Comment: 1) it is content-type 2) if you tag jQuery, why not USE jQuery (.get or .ajax) 3) use json_encode on the server

Comment: What is the content of the variable `$result` is it an array you want..?

Comment: Yes, `jQuery.ajax()` is simple and easy to use. ref:http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax

Comment: @Sherin:  php echos:  array(1) { [0]=> array(2) { ["logoImage"]=> string(13) "img/logo1.jpg" ["groupName"]=> string(12) "Group Melago" } }  I want to be able put those 2 data (img/logo1.jpg  & Group Melago)  under var image  and  var group variables.

Comment: Is the array contains only on row...?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this with [jquery AJAX](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/). Try the following code ,

**JQUERY**

```
<script>
$.ajax({
    type:'GET',
    url:'../thephp.php',
    dataType:'json',
    success: function(response){
        var image   =   response[0].logoImage,
            group   =   response[0].groupName;
    }
});
</script>
```

In **thephp.php**

```
$query = $db->prepare('SELECT logoImage, groupName FROM sports WHERE eligible = ? ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 1');
$array = array('N');
$query->execute($array);
$result = $query->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
echo json_encode($result);
```

Answer (score 1):

**PHP CODE:**

```
$query = $db->prepare('SELECT logoImage, groupName FROM sports WHERE eligible = ? ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 1');
$array = array('N');
$query->execute($array);
$result = $query->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
var $jsonData=json_encode($result )
var_dump($jsonData);
```

**JQUERY CODE:**

```
$.ajax({
     url:"../thephp.php",
     dataType: "json",
     success: 
      function(jsonData) {
          //parse the json data returned from server 
      }
 });
```

Happy Coding :)